# Add "where" query in Sequalize based on flag

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to add "where" query in Sequalize based on flag . Let me know how to get this.

For example if the flag is true then I want to add this "where" class otherwise I don't want to add the "where" clause.

```
models.Users.findAll({
        where: {
            email: req.query.email
        }
    }).then(function (list) {
        res.send(list);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    });



models.Users.findAll({
    }).then(function (list) {
        res.send(list);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    });
```

Comment: What is the flag? Some outside boolean variable not connected with the Model at all?

Comment: Yes ..Some outside boolean . true or false .

Answer (score 1):

You can create JSON first which you are providing in where clause and then pass it in where clause.. something like

```
var jsonObj = null ;

if (req.query.email){
   jsonObj =  {"email": req.query.email};
} else {
   jsonObj =  {"email": {$ne:null}}; //otherwise it will return all rows, if email is not null in your database
}

models.Users.findAll({
        where: jsonObj
    }).then(function (list) {
        res.send(list);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    });
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can start with an empty query object, and add a `where` property to it when appropriate:

```
let query = {};

if (someCondition) {
  query.where = { email: req.query.email };
}
models.Users.findAll(query).then(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple [one-line **`if`** statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) inside the `findAll` method call. Let's assume that `variable` is your boolean flag

```
models.Users.findAll(variable ? { where: { email: req.query.email } } : {}).then(list => {
    res.send(list);
}).catch(error => {
    res.status(500).json(error);
});
```

Or you can assign the `options` object to a variable and use the same `if` statement, but outside the `findAll` call

```
let options = variable ? { where: { email: req.query.email } } : {};

models.Users.findAll(options).then(list => {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: What do you mean not working? Some error appears or what happens?